# How to reduce 5 sec to 1 sec for the cost of python list comprehension with million item

Tags: python, performance, optimization

Now our code have 3,000,000 id stored in set, the format is string,  I try to convert it to int using list comprehension. But it cost 5 sec, how can I reduce the cost of converting string to int for these 3,000,000 id?

Here is my testing code:

```
import random
import time


a = set()
for i in xrange(3088767):
    a.add(str(random.randint(10005907, 100000000)))

start = time.time()
ld = [int(i) for i in a]
end = time.time()
print end-start
```

The result is:

```
$python  -V
Python 2.6.5
$python  ld.py
5.53777289391
```

Comment: use a faster computer?

Comment: @MitchWheat  I want to know if any method can help this issue

Comment: Is performing 3 million string->int conversions something that happens frequently in your code? If so, it sounds like there are much more effective ways to improve its performance (namely, storing it as an int in the first place...)

Comment: @DavidRobinson I get them from redis, and they are string not int.

Comment: @linbo: Is there any way that caching could improve your performance? (Are they always a new 3M strings or do most of them repeat with each repitition?) Perhaps there is another way to improve performance if you share more details.

Comment: @DavidRobinson  Yes, they are always a new 3M string, for the future maybe 4M, 10M, I don't know.  First we get them in mysql, but too slow, that's why using a cache.

Comment: @linbo: Do you always access all the integers in the list, or is it likely that you get a list of 3M strings, but you don't actually need all of them?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe we need all of them always

Answer (score 5):

```
ld = map(int, a)
```

should be quite faster, and also your only option not considering other python implementations

Comment: For map, Yes, I test it, it cost 4 sec

Comment: @jurgenreza my result is 4.35554289818. 0.0? I don't think it is reasonable, it should cost some time. Or maybe my machine is too slow.

Comment: Using `map` improves the runtime from ~3.8 to 3.0 seconds on my system.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Pypy](http://pypy.org) or [Cython](http://cython.org).

These tools can made your code fly! (Pypy, specially, in my PC Pypy speed up the code 4 times..)

Comment: And yes, is another Python implementation, but..

Comment: Yes, it is an solution, I will test them. Thanks

Comment: @linbo Good know (not everyone accepts other python implementation as solution). Good test! (and start with Pypy first, it's VERY recommended, as Cython need some rewrite of your code)

Comment: Well, we have lots of python code, not sure move to Pypy works or not.

Comment: @linbo Pypy only has incompatibility with some few codes. Here are a util link for see the compatibility: http://pypy.org/compat.html - Just code and you code just speed up! ;)

Comment: Thanks for your kind help, I will test my code in Pypy.